# Month till date in python for a generic way

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get two dates, where my starting date is the start of the current month and ending date is the today's date-1  of the same month.

For example if today is *25th April*, then I want two dates *1st April* and *24th April*. But this should be done in a generic way

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, repoducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using python's `datetime` module which helps to work with date and times in python. You can refer the following code to get an idea of how it can be done.

### Code -

```
from datetime import datetime
# Getting today's date using datetime.now() 
DateToday = datetime.now()

# converting into DD M(name) YYYY format using strftime
# ans1 will store start of month date
ans1 = datetime(DateToday.year,DateToday.month,1).strftime("%d %b, %Y")
# ans2 will store the date of one day before today
ans2 = datetime(DateToday.year,DateToday.month,DateToday.day-1).strftime("%d %b, %Y")

DateToday = DateToday.strftime("%d %b, %Y")

print("Today's Date :\t\t\t",DateToday)
print("First day of Month Date :\t",ans1)
print("Last day's Date:\t\t",ans2)
```

I have commented the code explaining what each statement of code does. You can learn more about python's `datetime` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).